# How to earn the Peer Pressure achievement?

Tags: discussion, badges

I saw it on badges, how do I get MINUS votes?

also, what does self-fulfilling prophecy mean?

Ilve already tried turning it off and on again and I've also tried to look at spicy memes for 20-30 minutes. halp?

Comment: Questions concerning this site belong on [meta].

Comment: This question is exactly why that badge should not exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At one hundred twenty five reputation, users gain the power of downvotes, which can cause a question to achieve a negative score.

For example, if 1 user decides a question is good, and 4 users decide it is bad, and vote accordingly, the net score will be -3.

The peer pressure badge was originally designed to encourage a potentially good behavior; to reward users for deleting questions that might be poorly recieved and are perhaps unwelcome on the site. However, it can also paradoxically entice bad behavior by allowing achievement hunters to be rewarded for asking bad questions and then deleting them for a badge.

The best way to earn the peer pressure badge is to not seek it in the first place.

Comment: this was intended to be a complete joke, but, ya know... good answer... so accept...

Comment: Happy to help as always

Comment: Unlike all other badges, the Peer Pressure badge is a badge of shame.

Comment: [Shame!](https://media.giphy.com/media/Ob7p7lDT99cd2/giphy.gif)

Comment: @MageXy or a consolation prize :-) (if "earned" legitimately)